# Can computers cause issues to retina?

Tags: eye, computers, eye-strain

I know working with computers can cause eyestrain and red eyes (and also the Computer Vision Syndrome). But recently I got some messages saying computers and mobile phone displays could cause **retinal disorders**.

*Is this true? What can be done to prevent retinal disorders?*

I frequently do some eye exercises which takes the pain off the eyes. *Would that be enough to keep the issues if caused by computers in balanced way?*

(EDIT: I'm not talking about computer vision syndrome, because as i mentioned i'm already taking measures for it.)

Comment: @Narusan possibly duplicate but i know about the computer vision syndrome and i'm taking measures for it. But recently i heard the screens affect the retina and causes retinal degeneration. That's what bugs me now :(

Comment: **I'd like to apologise**, I have only read your question in a hurry and the "computer" and "vision" keywords triggered me to think it was a duplicate. This is obviously not the case, your edit makes that very clear. I have edited your question even further with some proper spacing and highlighting the question itself while removing unnecessary background information. Feel free to accept the edit or to edit the question yourself.

Comment: @Narusan thanks for the edits mate :)